# Custom UIBarButton not appearing correctly in UITableView

Tags: uibarbuttonitem, navigationbar

I have code that successfully creates a custom UIBarButtonItem that appears on the navigation bar. I use the code in other view controllers, and it works perfectly, but in the UITableViewController, the button appears as the regular BackButtonItem. Can someone help me out? Here is the code that I use in the viewDidLoad method in all of the viewControllers

```
@implementation P2OListViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

    UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button-back@2x.png"];
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backButton setImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 35);

    [backButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(goToMenu:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:backButton];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = back;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

}

- (void)goToMenu:(id)sender {
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

@end

Answer (score 1):

hide the  default backBarButtonItem by setting its hide property to yes

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

in your viewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

    UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button-back@2x.png"];
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backButton setImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 35);

    [backButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(goToMenu:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:backButton];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = back;

}
```

if above not works try this & see what happens:

```
if (!self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.hidden) {
      self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.hidden = YES;
   }
   else { 
      NSLog(@"back button already hidden");
   }
```

Comment: I tried putting this code in the init method and viewDidLoad methods, and it is not working.

Comment: first make leftBarButtonItem nil & then hide bak button & then assign your custom button to leftBarbutton, try these in viewWillAppear

Comment: It still isn't working. I don't know why it does not work. I am using storyboards, so I can't hide the back button before the view is pushed onto the stack.

Comment: I left out the delegate methods because I haven't used them yet.

Comment: @ChandlerDeAngelis: write in viewWillAppear method

Comment: you have written in viewDidLoad

Comment: I do not have anything in the method. I tried putting the code that creates the button in that method, but it did not work so I moved it back to the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: I tried your solution but it is still not working, and the NSLog is not appearing in the debugger area, so I have no idea why this won't work.

Comment: is you have used tabBarController in this viewControler

Comment: write this on first line in viewWillAppear [super viewWillAppear:animated];

Comment: I am not using the tabBarController, and I added that first line in viewWillAppear, and it still isn't working.